# How to keep up to date my topic branch in GIT?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I have master branch (It is working copy), then some point in time I created another branch named topic and was working under it.

But yesterday I did rebase on master branch. Now when I build my project, it is able to build in master branch but not on topic branch.

Can anyone guide me what can be issue ? 
Some one suggested that I do need to keep up to date topic branch. Not sure; in what terms upto date(master or remote) ? how can I do in git ?

I google it; but does nt make sense which command ll save me ?

I thank you vm in adv.

In Detail:
my master branch(master_branch) is evolved; but my local branch(topic_branch) does contain only specific commit, which I made. Hence, some of the latest changes in master branch(master_branch) necessary as integrated with other repo; hence my build fails in topic_branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you haven't given a lot of information about your error, but if you successfully rebased against master, then your topic branch is up to date.  But up to date doesn't necessarily mean working, my guess is that recent changes in the master branch are incompatible with changes in your topic branch.  Because the master branch can build but the topic branch can't, the problem is somewhere in your topic branch.

Comment: Well it fails in other repo !

Comment: my master branch(master_branch) is evolved; but my local branch(topic_branch) does contain only specific commit, which I made. Hence, some of the latest changes in master branch(master_branch) necessary as integrated with other repo; hence my build fails in topic_branch.

Answer (score 0):

You said you "did rebase on master branch."  If you mean, while working on the master branch, you ran "git rebase $other_thing", then you probably need to switch to your topic branch and run "git rebase master" there.  Otherwise, your topic branch will be down-level of your master branch.